# File Upload not working after moving form field

Tags: forms, upload, atk4

I have a large form with a image upload field working ok.

Field is defined in model as:

```
$this->add('filestore/Field_Image','thumbnail_id');
```

Then I created two tabs inside form:

```
$tabs=$form->add('Tabs');
$main=$tabs->addTab('General');
$design=$tabs->addTab('Design');
```

And moved image field to design tab:

```
$design->add($form->getElement('thumbnail_id'));
```

Now I can't upload files. When I try I get the following javascript error
`Error: cannot call methods on atk4_form prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'submitPlain`

Is there any other way to move the field or have upload working again after moving it?

Comment: I suspect it's somehow related with the name of the field. Try moving the field using jQuery's appendTo ...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use the same method ($design->add($form->getElement('my_element'));) to move a slider into another place on the page. That didn't work - I think it was because the slider input field is not placed on the page the same way as other input fields.

So I tried with the jQuery appendTo-method (I found the hint in a comment from romanish in a documentation page). That worked. But then I experienced the same problem as you - and in the end I gave up and solved the problem by editing the slider-class page.

So I can't help you, sorry, but I guess this points out that there is a general problem related to getting input from moved form elements.